Terminal input with read system call: answer to first question is treated as the answer for all questions?
I'm making an Akinator-like game in NASM.
If I type the answer for the first question it makes it the answer for all the questions
It is a simple yes or no answer.
please help fix it and if you can give an explanation.
Below is the code.
 section .data
; questions
    q1 db 'Is your character real? (yes/no)', 0
    q2 db 'Is your character human? (yes/no)', 0
    q3 db 'Is your character male? (yes/no)', 0
    q4 db 'Is your character fictional? (yes/no)', 0
    q5 db 'Is your object/animal living? (yes/no)', 0

; answers
    a1 db 'red', 0
    a2 db 'jabol', 0
    a3 db 'kuromi', 0
    a4 db 'pencil', 0

section .bss
    answer resb 2
  

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; q1
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, q1
    mov edx, 24
    int 0x80
    
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, answer
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80

    cmp byte [answer], 'yes'
    je human
    cmp word [answer], 'no'
    je object_animal

human:
    ; Question 2
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, q3
    mov edx, 30
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, answer
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80
    
    cmp byte [answer], 'yes'
    je male
    cmp word [answer], 'no'
    je female

male:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, a1
    mov edx, 13
    int 0x80
    jmp exit

female:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, a2
    mov edx, 8
    int 0x80
    jmp exit

object_animal:
    ; Question 3
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, q5
    mov edx, 30
    int 0x80
    
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, answer
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80
    
    cmp byte [answer], 'yes'
    je living
    cmp word [answer], 'no'
    je non_living

living:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, a3
    mov edx, 5
    int 0x80
    jmp exit

non_living:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, a4
    mov edx, 6
    int 0x80
    jmp exit

exit:
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80


What do you see when running it under strace ./a.out to trace system calls?  Does the program make any more system calls?  What do you actually type?  You only read 2 bytes from the terminal, but your program compares against byte 'yes' (so actually byte 'y') and word 'no').  If you typed something as long as "yes", that would be 4 bytes including the newline.

Works for me; I type y (enter), then it prints a second question; I type n (enter) and according to strace it does write(1, "red\0jabol\0kur", 13).  So that's 2 and a half outputs since your length is wrong.  (And your strings don't include newlines.)  But it waited for input to the second question. Unlike if I'd typed yes or no.  Use a larger buffer like 100 bytes; that's good enough for a toy program to usually consume a line unless the user intentionally typed a long one, or unless they redirect from a file...  read isn't fgets, the one-line-at-a-time stuff comes from the TTY
